# Prototypical inheritance and function references as applied to function references/scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this, pass-by-reference, prototype-programming

Let's say I have the following two directives:

```
angular.module('demo').directive('functional', [function (){
  var idempotentMethods = ['idempotentMethod', 'otherIdempotentMethod'];
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'demoObject': '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    link: function (scope){
      for(var i = 0; i < idempotentMethods.length - 1; i++){
        scope[idempotentMethods[i]] = function(){
          scope.demoObject[idempotentMethods[i]]();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]);

angular.module('demo').directive('nonFunctional', [function (){
  var idempotentMethods = ['idempotentMethod', 'otherIdempotentMethod'];
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'demoObject': '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    link: function (scope){
      for(var i = 0; i < idempotentMethods.length; i++){
        scope[idempotentMethods[i]] = scope.demoObject[idempotentMethods[i]];
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

And the following factory:

```
angular.module('demo').factory('demoFactory', ['$resource', function(resource){

  var DemoFactory = resource('demo.json');

  angular.extend(DemoFactory.prototype, {
    idempotentMethod: function () {
      return this.$get();
    },
    otherIdempotentMethod: function () {
      return this.$get();
    }
  });

  return DemoFactory;
}]);
```

In the functional directive when scope.idempotentMethod() is triggered (through an `ng-click` or otherwise), the INCORRECT Factory method gets called.

In the nonFunctional directive it triggers

```
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.angular.extend.idempotentMethod
    at $parseFunctionCall
    at callback
    at Scope.$eval
```

In the Factories method. 
This suggests two things.
1) The function reference is binding (as expected),however only the last function reference is binding.
2) The `this` reference is incorrect. Printing out `this` in the Factory methods appears to corroborate this, with the non-Functional directive producing Scope, while the functional directive produces a Resource.

What is causing these two behaviours? Why is the this reference binding incorrectly? Why is the wrong function being called?

A plunkr demoing the problem: http://plnkr.co/B52DV0jmSWXc0M6GAamM

Comment: Did you try `console.log(i)` before `scope.demoObject[idempotentMethods[i]]();` I think you set the closure wrong and that may cause some problem if idempotentMethods has more then one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the way you set the closure:

```
function createBound(){
  var fn = function(){console.log('this is:',this);}
  ,i = -1//ret items are set using the value i inside createBound
    //by the time we call the function the value of i is 2
  ,ret = [];
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    ret.push(function(){
      console.log('i is:',i);//says 2 every time
      fn.call({hello:'world'});
    });
  }
  return ret;                                  
}
var bound = createBound();
bound[0]();
bound[1]();
```

correct way:

```
function createBound(){
  var fn = function(){console.log('this is:',this);}
  ,i = -1
  ,ret = [];
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    ret.push(
      (function(i,fn){//IIFE returning a function with correct i and fn
        //the value of i and fn that are passed are used in the returned closure
        //scope is within this IIFE, not within createBound
        return function(){
          console.log('i is:',i);//says: 0,1
          fn.call({hello:'world'});
        };
      }(i,fn))//end of IIFE where i and fn are passed to create a new closure
    );
  }
  return ret;                                  
}
var bound = createBound();
bound[0]();
bound[1]();
```

**[UPDATE]**

In your code to pass the correct closure you can do:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < idempotentMethods.length - 1; i++){
    scope[idempotentMethods[i]] = (function(i,idempotentMethods){
      return function(){
        scope.demoObject[idempotentMethods[i]]();
      };
    }(i,idempotentMethods));
  }
```

Please note that i doesn't count to the end of idempotentMethods that is why your code executes `idempotentMethods[idempotentMethods.length-1]` when ng-click is triggered.

Comment: That's an awesome explanation of the first problem. Closures hurt my head :(. Any thought on why the other approach, passing a function reference directly doesn't work and how I could force a correct this reference?

Comment: @AbrahamP when you do $scope.someFunction=someFunction the value of this in someFunction will be $scope. That is why you pass a closure or use bind.

Comment: @AbrahamP Updated the answer with code you can use to pass the correct closure.